# Stof doctrine extensions bundle xml mapping for tree and translatable

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Does anyone know how to configure xml mapping for http://gediminasm.org/article/tree-nestedset-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2? There is the example only with annotations

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as using annotations. In symfony2 in same xml files where you define the mapping add extra mapping information for extensions, all examples are located in the documentation: on [github](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/doc) or [my blog](http://www.gediminasm.org/)

Comment: I want to mix configuration for tree and translatable extension with xml mapping, could you provide the example for xml? in the links above is there configuration for annotations and yml only in section "Advanced examples: Nesting Translatatable and Sluggable extensions" on github:...